# Jupyter Docker Image Kernel Disconnected 400 Apache Proxy

Tags: websocket, jupyter-notebook, reverse-proxy, apache2.4

I have a Jupiter notebook running on an Ubuntu server in AWS.

```
docker run -d -p 8880:8888 jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

I am able to see the web interface just fine, and I've bashed into the container and gotten the token to log in.  That all seems good.  However, at the bottom of the web interface it says

```
Python 3 (ipykernel)|Disconnected
```

running the following line:

```
docker logs --tail -50 [container ID]
```

I get:

```
[I 2023-04-24 17:57:38.251 ServerApp] Kernel started: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f
[I 2023-04-24 17:57:38.252 ServerApp] Kernel shutdown: 3b58c1be-aba7-4c0a-9082-f4cfb1252c02
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:42.447 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 10.54ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:43.223 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.23ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:44.921 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:44.922 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.54ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:47.883 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:47.884 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.31ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:49.846 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:49.847 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.57ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:53.474 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:53.475 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.37ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:53.659 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/events/subscribe?token=[secret] (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 1.24ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:54.621 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:54.622 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.47ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:56.044 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969
[W 2023-04-24 17:57:56.045 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.61ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:58:01.418 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969
[W 2023-04-24 17:58:01.425 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 14.36ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:58:02.346 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8
[W 2023-04-24 17:58:02.347 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=41770cc1-2ec4-4827-8769-25f415657ee8 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.54ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:58:03.855 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/events/subscribe?token=[secret] (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 1.23ms referer=None
[W 2023-04-24 17:58:10.132 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f:0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969
[W 2023-04-24 17:58:10.133 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/kernels/26f0e339-31c1-4fc6-8bf0-4208454c652f/channels?session_id=0ab9b092-1a9a-4e13-a5b6-c18a343b7969 (619eb7cca8e94cf78a766772e4d1a559@172.17.0.1) 2.55ms referer=None
```

What I have read suggests that this is a problem with my Apache2 reverse proxy, and Jupyter's use of websockets.  So, I configured the proxy like this (per https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html):

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>

        ServerName host.domain.com

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.domain.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.domain.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.domain.com/fullchain.pem
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia On

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8880/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8880/

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond ${HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
        RewriteCond ${HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://localhost:8880/$1" [P,L]

#        RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
#        RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-SSL" expr=%{HTTPS}
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Rewrite mod is already enabled.  After restarting Apache, there is no change.  I get the same log output and the notebook is still not connecting to the terminal.  Same result if I use base-notebook.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation I found that the following configuration works to proxy the websocket for the kernel to work:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>

        ServerName host.second.top

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.second.top/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.second.top/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.second.top/fullchain.pem
#       SSLProxyEngine On      (nope)
#       SSLProxyVerify none    (nope)
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia On

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8880/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8880/

       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond ${HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
       RewriteCond ${HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
       RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://localhost:8880/$1" [P,L]

        <Location "/api/kernels">
            ProxyPass ws://localhost:8880/api/kernels
            ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:8880/api/kernels
        </Location>

        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

The following are commands that helped with the troubleshooting:

```
docker run --rm --name notebook -d -p 8880:8888 jupyter/base-notebook

sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/[site]

docker logs --tail -50 notebook

sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```